# "higher than is normal" vs "higher than normal"

Tags: grammar

I am reading an e-book about hypnosis. There is a sentence in that book as follows:

" The next thing you could try is to see if your friend can alter the viewpoint so that they seem to be ***higher than is normal***, i.e. is floating or flying."

I have searched internet. I found only one other ***"higher than is normal"*** in the address

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hypertension

the meaning of hypertension is "blood pressure that is ***higher than is normal***"

I guess there is no difference in meaning between "higher than is normal" and "higher than normal". Am I right or not?

Comment: As you can see from [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+higher+than+is+normal%2Cis+higher+than+normal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) we ***very rarely*** include the completely unnecessary second instance of [TO BE] in such contexts. But it doesn't carry any significance if we do include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. There is no difference in meaning between **higher than normal** and **higher than is normal**. IMHO, the  *is* in the latter sentence is redundant and my preference would be for the first sentence.